# Multiple column insertion android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-sqlite

I am using SQLLite Database supplied by Android.

I have a Table myTable with two coloumns: col_id and colName.
The gettersetter class is as follows:

```
 public class MyTable{

        private long id;
    private String colName;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getColName() {
        return colName;
    }

    public void setColName(String colName) {
        this.colName = colName;
    }

}
```

I have a method in database connector which inserts a single row :

```
 public void insertMyTable(String colName)
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("colName", colName);
              open();
              database.insert("myTable", null, newCon);
              close();
           }
```

Is there a way to insert a List of objects of type MyTable into the database, i have over 100 records to be inserted at once.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void insertMyTable(List<MyTable> myTables)
{
    open();
    database.beginTransaction();
    for (MyTable myTable : myTables)
    {
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("colName", myTable.getColName());
        database.insert("myTable", null, insertValues);
    }  
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nguyen for the response. However i was looking to use the gettersetter class to insert the value. Anyway to inser a single or multiple value?